# set nsdate format for iphone

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want date in below format.

**04/22/2011 1:05:21 PM**

format is **mm/dd/yyyy time(12 hour) pm or AM**

what is the code for this?

Comment: If your app is going to be a multilingual app, I would suggest not using static date formatter. But ask the system for the currentlocal and it formatting behaviour. (in Europa we don't use AM/PM)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
    NSDate *date=[NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSString *dateOfGame =[formatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"dateOfGame%@",dateOfGame);
    [formatter release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (and [Date Formatting](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1))

`MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a`

Answer (score 1):

some other type

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
 NSLog(@"date=%@",[formatter stringFromDate:date]);//date=04/22/2011

[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
NSLog(@"date=%@",[formatter stringFromDate:date]);// date=1:05:11 PM

[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
NSLog(@"date=%@",[formatter stringFromDate:date]); date=

[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
NSLog(@"date=%@",[formatter stringFromDate:date]); date=1:05:11 PM India Standard Time

[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSLog(@"date=%@",[formatter stringFromDate:date]); date=1:05:11 PM GMT+05:30

[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSLog(@"date=%@",[formatter stringFromDate:date]); date=1:05:11 PM

[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
NSLog(@"date=%@",[formatter stringFromDate:date]);date=

[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSLog(@"date=%@",[formatter stringFromDate:date]); date=1:05 PM
```